# Discrepancy between results of EXACT function and Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, exact-match

I'm observing an apparent discrepancy between the results of the EXACT function and the conditional formatting tool.

Two cells in Column B have the same apparent text (about 30-40 words).  But the "highlight cells" tool doesn't recognize them as duplicate values. Comparing the two cells with the EXACT function returns TRUE, however.  This also occurs when comparing the results of the CLEAN function applied to both cells. The cells include characters like "//" and square brackets (although why that should be a problem I don't know, especially since other such cell are correctly identified as duplicates by conditional formatting tool).

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

An example, obfuscated with U=uppercase, x=lowercase and d=digit:

> (U//FOUO) UUUU-U Increment d shall comply with current UUUxxx and UUUU Meta Data Repository (MDR) commercial, DoD, and Intelligence Community (IC) metadata standards and shall have a xxxx-xxxxxxxx controlled metadata tagging capability to tag all messages, products, and data files that are posted to the network (MRIC=Objective). [0014] [Interoperability]

Comment: Can you post the actual values of these cells?  Trying it on my ends works fine .. so without any idea what your data looks like, can't help :(

Comment: @ditto, I can't, actually, because the contents are proprietary, but what follows is an obfuscation where U=uppercase, x=lowercase and d=digit: (U//FOUO) UUUU-U Increment d shall comply with current UUUxxx and UUUU Meta Data Repository (MDR) commercial, DoD, and Intelligence Community (IC) metadata standards and shall have a xxxx-xxxxxxxx controlled metadata tagging capability to tag all messages, products, and data files that are posted to the network (MRIC=Objective).  [0014] [Interoperability]

Comment: O.o sorry, can't understand. Can you clearly tell us what values are in what cells?  eg    A1="Hello world"  B1="Another World"   Then we have something tangible we can see.  And yes, by all means, obfuscate, or simplify the data if need be.

Comment: (U//FOUO) UUUU-U Increment d shall comply with current UUUxxx and UUUU Meta Data Repository (MDR) commercial, DoD, and Intelligence Community (IC) metadata standards and shall have a xxxx-xxxxxxxx controlled metadata tagging capability to tag all messages, products, and data files that are posted to the network (MRIC=Objective). [0014] [Interoperability] 

The text shown above (as obfuscated) appears in two different cells in the same column.  Although the EXACT function confirms both cells contain the same thing, the conditional formatting tool, does not recognize them as the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a 255 character limit to the Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells Rules..., Duplicate Values... rule. To me plausible since consistent with the limit for characters in a formula in VBA.

A simple way to check is to apply such a rule to both the column with your data and to an inserted adjacent column (say C) populated with a formula such as:

```
=LEFT(B1,255)
```

That I expect to highlight the extracted characters. Then change the formula to `=LEFT(B1,256)` and I expect the formatting to disappear.

If so, you might insert another column (say D) populated with `=RIGHT(B1,255)` and, assuming your data is less than 510 characters per cell, you may have a workaround for detecting duplicates by applying the rule to ColumnsC:D.

Comment: "It seems there is a 255 character limit to the Conditional Formatting"  Is that still a limit in the newer versions of Excel? I recall hitting this issue in the past (now that you mention it) - and worked around it by putting longer formulas into cells (as you mentioned), then do the conditional formatting off those cells. Still, Excel does have it's limits :)